# Stata: code binary variable conditional on key words in string variable

Tags: stata, binary-data

Is there any way to code a binary variable dependent on keywords being present in a given string variable? Simple example:

I have a string variable that describes various meals and a dummy variable that denotes if a given meal is breakfast or not. Is there any way to code

breakfast = 1 if meal== [then something saying contains eggs, bacon, etc.]

This is a silly example, but I am more interested in identifying a shortcut to coding binary variables, based on information found in string data.

Answer (score 3):

The inbuilt `strpos()` will yield a positive value if a string is found inside another. Building on that

```
 gen breakfast = strpos(meal, "bacon") | strpos(meal, "eggs")
```

and so forth. In practice, working with a string made lower case will often help, or indeed be essential. Also, if you have a long list, you may prefer

```
 gen breakfast = 0 
 quietly foreach thing in bacon eggs cereal "orange juice" { 
       replace breakfast = breakfast | strpos(lower(meal), `"`thing'"') 
 }
```

The principle here is using | (or) as a logical operator, yielding 1 (true) if any argument is non-zero. Note that `lower()` is included to compare with a lower case version of the original.

This technique is naturally not robust to spelling mistakes or small variations in wording.

Comment: Thanks. `strpos()` is a function, strictly; in Stata functions and commands are disjoint, to the surprise and/or irritation of some users more accustomed to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the incss function of the egenmore package for this.

```
ssc install egenmore
egen bacon = incss(meal), sub(bacon) insensitive
```

This gives you a dummy equal to one if for a given observation the string variable "meal" contains the word bacon. It is zero otherwise. The option insensitive tells Stata to not consider case sensitivity (otherwise Bacon is different from bacon). As far as I know you can only search for one sub-string at a time but you can easily write a loop for this:

```
foreach word in bacon eggs cheese {
egen `word' = incss(meal), sub(`word') insensitive
}
```

Comment: This is great--thank you! Do you know where I can find the egenmore package?

Comment: That information was implicit: you can install it from the SSC archive. (Much though I like `incss()` -- indeed I wrote it -- there are alternatives here. I will answer separately.)

Comment: @NickCox I'm new to STATA, so navigating the logistics of managing the tool is tricky. I asked for clarification because I know that other newcomers have difficulty with this as well. Thank you for the further info. http://repec.org/docs/ssc.php is a link that has modules for interested parties. To get the package, type "ssc install egenmore" into STATA.

Comment: Indeed, but had you followed the code suggestion or looked up `ssc` to find out what it does you would have found out for yourself. If the expectation is that every line of code has to be explained that is a tough call on people who take the time to answer questions. Also, note that the spelling is "Stata".

Comment: Note that the advantage, if there is one, of `incss()` is that it automates looking for one specific substring within several string variables. The problem here is looking for several specific substrings within one string variable, so I recommend the approach spelled out in my separate answer.